# How would you count the number of matches between a comma-separated list and a reference column in Excel?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

I have a set of numbers separated by commas. Each set represents a series of unique numbers that relate to a project. How can I write a formula to search a reference sheet for any number of the items in the list, and return a hard-coded value?

I'll include examples (de-identified) below for each sheet (**tables 1-5**) and the intended/expected output. I would imagine it is something to do with SUM, FREQUENCY, INDEX, or some other array formula, but I can't figure it out. You can see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60732559/how-can-you-check-if-data-in-a-cell-row-appears-in-a-cell-column-across-mult) also, but it has much the same info.

I've used "**P**ass" "**F**ail" and "**M**issing" but anything works.

Logic:

The formula should perform the following steps.

1. Extract the list of numbers from each cell in column C of **table 4**.
2. Search **table 3** (column D) for instances of the numbers in the list.
   2b. If any number in the list appears, check to see if the audit has failed (denoted by the text "failed" in column B of **table 3**).
   2c. If it has, print **F**.
   2d. If it has not, print **P**.
3. If none of the numbers in the list appear, print **M**.

Tables:

**table 1**

This table is the main reference sheet. It lists every UID against the name, server, and project.

```
 Unique ID     Name         Server Address     Project
 10000         Company 1    Server 1           Project 1
 10001         Company 2    Server 2           Project 2
 10002         Company 3    Server 3           Project 3
 10003         Company 3    Server 3           Project 4
 10004         Company 3    Server 3           Project 5
 10005         Company 3    Server 3           Project 6
 10006         Company 4    Server 4           Project 7
 10007         Company 4    Server 4           Project 7
 10008         Company 4    Server 4           Project 7
 10009         Company 5    Server 5           Project 8
 10010         Company 6    Server 6           Project 9
 10011         Company 7    Server 7           Project 10
 10012         Company 8    Server 8           Project 11
 10013         Company 8    Server 8           Project 11
 10014         Company 8    Server 8           Project 11
 10015         Company 8    Server 8           Project 11
 10016         Company 8    Server 8           Project 11
 10017         Company 8    Server 8           Project 11
 10018         Company 8    Server 8           Project 11
 10019         Company 8    Server 8           Project 11
 10020         Company 8    Server 8           Project 11
 10021         Company 9    Server 9           Project 12
 10022         Company 10   Server 10          Project 13
 10023         Company 11   Server 10          Project 14
 10024         Company 12   Server 10          Project 15
 10025         Company 13   Server 10          Project 16
 10026         Company 14   Server 10          Project 17
 10027         Company 15   Server 10          Project 18
 10028         Company 16   Server 10          Project 19
 10029         Company 17   Server 10          Project 20
 10030         Company 18   Server 10          Project 21
 10032         Company 19   Server 10          Project 23
 10033         Company 19   Server 10          Project 24
```

**table 2**

this table has all the same info as **table 1** but groups each UID to its' respective project. I don't currently actually use it, but it might be helpful? I will delete if not.

```
 Company Trading Name     Project     UID     UID     UID     UID
 Company 1                Project 1   10000
 Company 2                Project 2   10001
 -----------------------------------------------------
 Company 4                Project 7   10006   10007   10008
```

**table 3**

this table is where the audit results are pasted. They follow this layout exactly, with the notes column having the word failed if the audit has not passed (conditional formatting highlights this currently), and the UID getting pulled out by a simple LEFT function. The Name and company columns then use a VLOOKUP against the UID in **table 1** to grab the name/server.

```
Notes                                   Time Rec.      UID     Name        Server
Audit for company passed:10001          auto           10001   Company 2   Server 2  
Audit for company passed:10006          auto           10006   Company 4   Server 4
Audit for company failed:10007          auto           10007   Company 4   Server 4
```

**table 4**

This is the audit sheet. The formula would go into column D, and the output copy/pasted as values each day. I've filled some examples in here of what it should look like afterwards.

```
 Server     Name         Project (UID)                          Today's Date
 Server 1   Company 1    Project 1 (10000)                       P
 Server 2   Company 2    Project 2 (10001)                       N
 Server 3   Company 3    Project 3 (10002,10003,10004,10005)     F
 Server 4   Company 4    Project 4 (10006,10007,10008)           P
 -----------------------------------------------------
 Server 10  Company 10  Project 13 (10022)                       P
 Server 10  Company 11  Project 14 (10023)                       M
 Server 10  Company 12  Project 15 (10024)                       P
 Server 10  Company 13  Project 16 (10025)                       P
 Server 10  Company 15  Project 18 (10027)                       F
 Server 10  Company 16  Project 19 (10028)                       P
 Server 10  Company 17  Project 20 (10029)                       M
 Server 10  Company 18  Project 21 (10030)                       P
 Server 10  Company 19  Project 22 (100310)                      P
 Server 10  Company 19  Project 23 (10032)                       P
 Server 10  Company 19  Project 24 (10033)                       M
```

Alternatively I have a fifth table, **table 5**, which automatically looks up any missing ID's from **table 3** using the following formula:

`=INDEX(Reference!$A$2:$A$160, SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Reference!$A$2:$A$160, Check!$D$2:$D$350, 0)), (ROW(Reference!$A$2:$A$160)-MIN(ROW(Reference!$A$2:$A$160))+1), ""), ROWS($A$1:A1)))`

When **table 3** is empty (it is cleared each day), this simply lists every project. When any number of audits are pasted into **table 3** however, the list in **table 5** will update to show which are missing. There may be a way to incorporate this into a final formula, perhaps.

I have a de-identified version if anyone wants one to work with.

Thank you.

edit1: Someone requested more system details. This is in a Windows 10 environment using Excel 365.

Comment: Add to your question. What OS and a OS tag.

Comment: I've added the details (though I am not sure why they are relevant, I am curious; does excel have different functionality across OS?) - this is on Windows 10. The tags already included excel-365, but I've clarified in an edit at the bottom of the post regardless.

Comment: Does this mean that output 'Y' is applicable when for all numbers (say in a row of table 4) audit has Passed and in case if it's a single number anyways it should be 'Y' if Audit has Passed?

Comment: @somebadhat I can't see why OS is relevant here.

Comment: @patkim That's right. To try and clarify I've used "Pass" "Fail" "Missing" now, but any project where all the audits (one for each UID) that are received are not failures gets a pass. If there are any number of audits received and any number of those failed, the project gets a failed instead. If no audits are received the project gets a "missing".

Comment: Since this is a mock data, would like to know if the actual UIDs are going to be numeric values or they may contain alphabets too? Secondly what if in a comma separated list say 2 UIDs one is Pass but other is Missing? What should be the end result in such a case?

Comment: @patkim yes, UID are always numeric. If a project gets a passed audit for 2/3 of it's UID and no audit for the third, it counts as a Pass, because all received audits were passes. If any received audits are failures it gets failed instead, and if none are received it gets missing.

Your example of one pass/one missing would be a pass.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to put together an approach which I admit is not very scaleable and uses a few helper columns. I am not too sure if there's a direct way to lookup comma separated values in one go. It might be possible but I am not that Excel expert.

Moreover I think Office 365 Desktop version supports VBA macros. If you have desktop version you may opt for a VBA macro solution that may be more streamlined. I think however Macros are not supported in Online version.

See the below snapshot.

[image]

There are 5 helper columns. H,M,N,O,P.
H may be optional but I prefer to use simple numeric sequence as your server names may not really be having last character as Numbers like Server 1, Server 2 in that order.

In M4 put the following formula and drag it down.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(K4,LEN(K4)-FIND("(",K4)),")","")
```

This creates a proper comma separated list of UIDs

In N4 put the following formula and drag it down up to provisional number of cells. When there's nothing to display cell contents will be blank but extend it down for later provisioning as UIDs count can vary.

```
=VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$M$4:$M$22),",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*99+1,99)))
```

In O4 put the following formula and drag it down.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(N4)),MATCH("*"&N4&"*",$M$4:$M$22,0),"")
```

This lists the positions of the UIDs which will be used later.

In P4 put the following formula and drag it down.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(N4)),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("passed",INDEX($B$4:$B$22,MATCH(VALUE(N4),$D$4:$D$22,0)))),"P",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("failed",INDEX($B$4:$B$22,MATCH(VALUE(N4),$D$4:$D$22,0)))),"F","M")),"")
```

This decides the status of each UID from Table 4.

Now the Output Column L in my example.

In L4 put the following formula and drag it down.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($O$4:$O$22,H4,$P$4:$P$22,"M")=COUNTIF($O$4:$O$22,H4),"M",IF(COUNTIFS($O$4:$O$22,H4,$P$4:$P$22,"P")+COUNTIFS($O$4:$O$22,H4,$P$4:$P$22,"M")=COUNTIF($O$4:$O$22,H4),"P","F"))
```

This applies the final logic to decide the audit status Pass Fail or Missing based on transposed list in Helper columns.

You may convert these data sets to Excel Tables and use Table[Header] references to make it more dynamic.

Try it out and decide if this could be useful to you.  I accept it's not that great as it uses several helper columns. The idea is to transpose comma separated list to contiguous cells and then apply the lookup.